# I'm calculating the band structure with and without considering spin orbit coupling. why I need to use SOC?

Tags: density-functional-theory

I have been working on electronic properties of ternary alkali Bismuth.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question is currently marked as a low-quality question. So to avoid it from being closed, please add more details such as relevant code, input files and other appropriate details.

Comment: I'm asking that, in band structure calculation of any compound, when and why we use spin orbit coupling?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For which elements should I include spin orbit coupling in Quantum ESPRESSO?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/for-which-elements-should-i-include-spin-orbit-coupling-in-quantum-espresso)

Comment: This question had a close vote triggered by "elutionary" and supported by myself, Abdul and Vandan (4 close votes, all on 2 June 2023), but a "leave open" vote by Vasista on 7 June. The close votes were invalidated on 22 June, after 20 days (5x4?). It does seem to be a duplicate to me.